# Select elements as expected, but only once, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table, that represent all CMS posts. 
I'm writing a feature that allows to select/de-select all post by clicking on "Check All/Uncheck All" `checkbox element`

For example, this will work as expected - No matter how many times you click on it.
If checkboxes are checked - it will alert "Check All is checked now"
Otherwise - it will alert "Check All is UNchecked now"

```
$("table thead input").click(function(){

 var checkboxes = $("table tbody tr input")

 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

   alert('Check All is checked now');
 } else {

    alert('Check All is UNchecked now');
  }
 });
```

Again - It works as expected.

However, if you replace `alert()` s with another logic, this no longer works as expected, but only once.

```
$("table thead input").click(function(){

 var checkboxes = $("table tbody tr input")

  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

  checkboxes.each(function(){   
    $(this).attr('checked', true);
  });

  } else {

    checkboxes.each(function(){

     $(this).attr('checked', false);
    });
  }
});
```

It will check/uncheck those checboxes, but only once - if you click on `$("table thead input")` more that once, it will not work.

**I've tried**, to `removeAttr('checked')` instead of `$(this).attr('checked', false)`, but with no luck.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr) to set the checked state

```
$(this).prop('checked', false);//to uncheck
$(this).prop('checked', true);//to check
```

[Attributes vs Properties](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#entry-longdesc)

Your code can be simplified to

```
$("table thead input").change(function () {
    var checkboxes = $("table tbody tr input");
    checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```

Or to below if the elements are not dynamic

```
//cache the checkbox reference
var checkboxes = $("table tbody tr input");
$("table thead input").change(function () {
    checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked)
});
```